# Xamarin bt scan callback and message center

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to send a message or broadcast an intent from OnScanResult for ble devices but i keep getting exceptions

```
public override void OnScanResult(ScanCallbackType callbackType, ScanResult result)
        {
            base.OnScanResult(callbackType, result);
            Intent i = new Intent(BluetoothDevice.ActionFound);
            i.PutExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraDevice, i);
            var device = result.Device;

            if (device != null)
            {
                Android.App.Application.Context.SendBroadcast(i);
                //  MessagingCenter.Send<IScanSender, Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothDevice>(this, "btScanner", device);

            }


        }
```

and  i am getting

```
Java.Lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND
```

for broadcasing intent

or
`System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation`.

for trying to send message

Comment: Bluetooth Permission?

Comment: There was a permission issue, Now i am getting a stackoverflow exception

Comment: Stackoverflow exception what is that kindly update it to the question?